# Operator in Hilbert Space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm new in the forum. I just started to study Operators in Hilbert Space. An exercise asks me :"

In the Hilbert Space $H=L^2(-\pi,\pi) $ it's defined the operator :

$ [Tf](x)= M\int_{-1/2M}^{1/2M} dy f(y)$,  where $M \gt  {1 \over\pi}.$

Find enginevalues, Ker, Im, Dom and, if it's limitated, calculate the norm. Analyze also the case $\lim_{M \to \infty}$

My point is until today I just worked with operators , defined by integrals, whose integration extremes were the same of Hilbert Space of definition.

So can I work in the same way I did before saying, for example,

$[Tf](x)= M\int_{-1/2M}^{1/2M} dy f(y) =(g, f)  $  g=1 ? Or should I work in different way?

What can I say about the limit?

Sorry but I just started studying this argument and my  notes are very terrible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no $x$ in your definition of $[Tf](x)$, maybe you did a mistake ?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I simply wrote the exact trace of the exercise. However do you know how should I work when the extremes of the integral operator are different from the extreme of L^2 space?